# Edit embedded resource (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, resources, bitmap, embedded-resource, edit

This should be simple, but Visual Studio stubbornly refuses to cooperate: I have a C# project (Visual Studio 2005) with bitmaps as embedded resources, BUT I CAN'T GET AT THEM!

I've been struggling with the GUI and MSDN "help", and can't get to the embedded bitmaps to edit them.  How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: Visual Studio has MULTIPLE .resx files!  I stumbled upon the one that had the bitmaps I needed to edit.  (Used to the old days, when all the resources were in one .RC file.)