# How to detect Edit Resource file programatically at run time?

Tags: asp.net, embedded-resource

if resource file in a folder then we can edit this like

```
XmlDocument loResource = new XmlDocument();
        loResource.Load(Server.MapPath("/App_GlobalResources/TDLResources.de-DE.resx"));

        XmlNode loRoot = loResource.SelectSingleNode("root/data[@name='RequiredFields']/value");

        if (loRoot != null)
        {
            loRoot.InnerText = "test";
            loResource.Save(Server.MapPath("/App_GlobalResources/TDLResources.de-DE.resx"));
        }
```

but if resource file is merge with in assembly then how could i edit this. help will be appreciated.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if that's possible if they are embeded resources. MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) suggest that it should be used as Linked Resource. Others also [say the same thing](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/124689/Is-it-able-to-modify-a-embedded-resource-file.aspx#answer2)

So see if something like this rescues you [Edit embedded resource (Visual Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503403/edit-embedded-resource-visual-studio)